# Best practices for resizing text on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out the best way of resizing text inside a div on different sized devices. In this demo, I've used the media query many times, but this doesn't feel like the most efficient way of doing it.

Does anyone have any better practices than this? Obviously my solution only accommodates for the exact amount of text in this demo, which wouldn't be great for other divs of the same size but with different amounts of text in.

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts.

```css
.first-news-article-description {
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
}
@media(max-width:768px) {
  .first-news-article-description {background:yellow}
  h2 {font-size: 1.2em}
}
@media(max-width:600px) {
  .first-news-article-description {background:red}
  h2 {font-size: 1.0em}
}
@media(max-width:450px) {
  .first-news-article-description {background:blue}
  h2 {font-size: 0.8em}
}
@media(max-width:350px) {
  .first-news-article-description {background:red}
  h2 {font-size: 0.7em}
}
```

```html
<div class="first-news-article-description">
            <h2>Some random text that needs to resize properly on different devices</h2>
            <span>Some more text</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just a small note on usability, text generally should never be smaller than 16px, for readability reasons. Even on mobile.

Comment: where did you hear this from? I remember reading somewhere the smallest could be 14px

Comment: [Here you go](https://webaim.org/techniques/fonts/#font_size) - and for reference, 16px (12pt) is "the default" here. Accessibility auditing tools, including Lighthouse (which is built-in to Chrome Dev Tools) will warn you for using text smaller than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a unit called `viewport width`. You can use it to resize the text-size without using media query. Find the example below

```html
<h1 style="font-size:4vw;">Hello World</h1>
<p style="font-size:2vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the font size scales.</p>
```

Comment: But what if I want the exact specific font size based screens size, such as he want 1.em for 768px, 1.0em for 600px etc.

Comment: `vw` will resize your text-size according to the viewport-width. In case if you want to maintain a particular font-size for a range of width, then I guess you need to with the media queries.